# Draw external pins only for connected pins

Tags: circuitikz

I'm trying to modify the CircuiTikZ manual's tutorial example (section 2.3) to apply the idea from section 4.24.4, i.e. using a modified `dipchip` for an opaque black-box block.

```
\ctikzset{
 logic ports=ieee,
 logic ports/scale=0.7,
 multipoles/dipchip/width=2
 }

\tikzset{block/.style=
  { dipchip
  , no topmark
  , hide numbers
  , external pins width=0.2
  }
}

\newcommand*{\myblock}[1]{% Add #1- to the node and coord names
node[block, num pins=6](#1-FF){SR-FF}
(#1-FF.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[and port, anchor=out](#1-AND1){}
(#1-FF.pin 3) -- (#1-FF.pin 3 -| #1-AND1.out) node[and port, anchor=out](#1-AND2){}
(#1-AND1.in 1) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(#1-in) to (#1-in |- #1-AND2.in 2) -- (#1-AND2.in 2);
}


\begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw (0,0) \myblock{A};
  \draw (0,-4) \myblock{B};

  \draw (A-in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) node[below]{$a_0$};
  \draw (B-in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) node[below]{$a_1$};
  \draw (A-AND1.in 2) to[short, -*] (A-AND2.in 1)
    to[short, -*] (B-AND1.in 2) to[short, -*] (B-AND2.in 1)
    -- ++(0, -2) coordinate(down) node[below]{ENABLE};
    \draw
      (A-FF.pin 2) 
      to[short, -*] (B-FF.pin 2) 
      -- (B-FF.pin 2 |- down) node[below]{CP};
\end{circuitikz}
```

This works as one would expect, resulting in the following picture:

[image]

The problem starts when I want to get rid of the external pin "whiskers" on unconnected pins. If I set `external pins width` to 0, they go away, but then then `CP` connection becomes ugly:

[image]

What I want to avoid is having to manually draw the external pins for connected pins, and having to offset coordinates by `(-0.2,0)` or `(0.2,0)` depending on the side, manually. Basically, I'd like to keep the automatic pins, and the automatic coordinates computed from them, but only for connected pins. For unconnected pins (such as pins 4, 5 and 6 in this example), I'd like to have no external pins at all.

How do I do that?

Comment: You might consider creating a new component, or simply using a rectangular node instead of a dip chip (which this aint).

Comment: ...why don't you use a `flipflop` instead of a `dipchip` here?

Comment: @Rmano because the eventual schematics I will need to draw will use blackbox blocks instead of flipflops or proper DIPs. So I started modifying the tutorial to get a hang of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following copies the code of `dipchip` and alters it to be able to pick specific pins only. The new shape is named `xdipchip` and uses all the parameters of `dipchip` (so looks just like that), but adds at two spots some checks for a specific list of pins (those code points are marked with `%% CHANGES HERE`).

The pins used can be controlled with the key `xdip pins` which takes as its value a comma separated list of pins which should be used. All anchors will be set at the correct spot, meaning the `pin \x` anchor will be placed at the tip of the pin for `\x` in the list of shown pins, else at the same spot as `bpin \x`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__xdipchip_pins_clist
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xdipchip@if@pin #1
  {\clist_if_in:NoTF \l__xdipchip_pins_clist { \the \numexpr #1 }}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/xdip~ pins/.code=\clist_set:Nn \l__xdipchip_pins_clist {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% code copied (and then altered) from pgfcircmultipoles.tex
\pgfdeclareshape{xdipchip}{
    \savedmacro{\ctikzclass}{\edef\ctikzclass{chips}}
    \saveddimen{\scaledRlen}{\pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
    \savedmacro\numpins{%
            \pgf@circ@count@a=\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/num pins}%
            \def\numpins{\the\pgf@circ@count@a}
    }
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
        \pgf@x=-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y=-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by+.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }%
    \savedanchor\origin{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \anchor{center}{\origin}
    \anchor{text}{\centerpoint}% to adjust text
    \saveddimen\height{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{((\numpins)
        *\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing})*\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen/2}%
    }%
    \saveddimen{\chipspacing}{
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen*\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing}}}
    \saveddimen{\width}{
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen*\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/width}}}
    \saveddimen{\extshift}{
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen*\ctikzvalof{multipoles/external pins width}}}
    % standard anchors
    \savedanchor\northwest{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{0.5*((\numpins)
        *\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing})*\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen/2}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{-0.5*\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen*\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/width}}
    }
    \anchor{dot}{\northwest
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@x + 0.3*\chipspacing}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@y - 0.3*\chipspacing}
    }
    \anchor{nw}{\northwest}
    \anchor{ne}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{se}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{sw}{\northwest\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{north west}{\northwest}
    \anchor{north east}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{south east}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x \pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{south west}{\northwest\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{n}{\northwest\pgf@x=0pt }
    \anchor{e}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x\pgf@y=0pt }
    \anchor{s}{\northwest\pgf@x=0pt\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{w}{\northwest\pgf@y=0pt }
    \anchor{north}{\northwest\pgf@x=0pt }
    \anchor{east}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x\pgf@y=0pt }
    \anchor{south}{\northwest\pgf@x=0pt\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{west}{\northwest\pgf@y=0pt }
    % start drawing
    \backgroundpath{%
        \northwest
        \pgf@circ@res@up = \pgf@y
        \pgf@circ@res@down = -\pgf@y
        \pgf@circ@res@right = -\pgf@x
        \pgf@circ@res@left = \pgf@x
        \pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen=\scaledRlen
        \pgf@circ@res@step = \ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing}\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen
        \pgf@circ@res@other = \ctikzvalof{multipoles/external pins width}\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen
        \pgfscope% (for the line width)
        \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{multipoles}{\pgflinewidth}
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-\width/2}{-\height/2}}{\pgfpoint{\width/2}{\height/2}}%
        \pgf@circ@draworfill
        %% upside mark
        \ifpgf@circuit@chip@topmark
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.2*\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpatharc{0}{180}{0.2*\pgf@circ@res@left}
        \fi
        \pgfusepath{stroke}%
        \pgfsetcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
        % Adding the pin number
        \ifpgf@circuit@chip@shownumbers
            \pgf@circ@count@a=\numpins\relax
            \divide\pgf@circ@count@a by 2 \pgf@circ@count@b=\pgf@circ@count@a
            % thanks to @marmot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473571/38080
            \ifpgf@circuit@chip@straightnumbers
                \pgfgettransformentries\a\b\temp\temp\temp\temp
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{-atan2(\b,\a)}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\quadrant}{mod(4+int(360+(\rot+45)/90),4)}
            \else
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{0}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\quadrant}{0}
            \fi
            \def\pgf@circ@strut{\vrule width 0pt height 1em depth 0.4em\relax}
            \def\mytext{\ctikzvalof{multipoles/font}\space\pgf@circ@strut\the\pgf@circ@count@c\space}
            \pgfmathloop%
            \ifnum\pgf@circ@count@a>0
                \ifcase\quadrant % rotation 0
                    % left
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\pgf@circ@count@a
                    \pgftext[left,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                    % right
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\numexpr2*\pgf@circ@count@b-\pgf@circ@count@a+1\relax
                    \pgftext[right,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                \or % rotation -90
                    % left
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\pgf@circ@count@a
                    \pgftext[top,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                    % right
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\numexpr2*\pgf@circ@count@b-\pgf@circ@count@a+1\relax
                    \pgftext[bottom,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                \or %rotation 180
                    % left
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\pgf@circ@count@a
                    \pgftext[right,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                    % right
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\numexpr2*\pgf@circ@count@b-\pgf@circ@count@a+1\relax
                    \pgftext[left,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                \or % rotation +90
                    % left
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\pgf@circ@count@a
                    \pgftext[bottom,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                    % right
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\numexpr2*\pgf@circ@count@b-\pgf@circ@count@a+1\relax
                    \pgftext[top,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                \fi
                \advance\pgf@circ@count@a-1\relax%
                \repeatpgfmathloop
            \fi
            \endpgfscope
            \ifdim\pgf@circ@res@other>0pt
            \pgfscope
                \pgfsetlinewidth{\ctikzvalof{multipoles/external pins thickness}\pgflinewidth}
                \pgf@circ@count@a=\numpins\relax
                \divide\pgf@circ@count@a by 2 \pgf@circ@count@b=\pgf@circ@count@a
                \pgfmathloop%
                \ifnum\pgf@circ@count@a>0
                    \edef\padfrac{\ctikzvalof{multipoles/external pad fraction}}
                    \ifnum\padfrac>0
                        \pgf@circ@res@temp=\pgf@circ@res@step\divide\pgf@circ@res@temp by \padfrac
                        % left side pads
                        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgf@circ@res@other}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        % right side pads
                        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right+\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right+\pgf@circ@res@other}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                    \else
                        %% CHANGES HERE
                        % left side pins
                        \xdipchip@if@pin\pgf@circ@count@a
                          {%
                            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                          }
                          {%
                            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                          }%
                        % right side pins
                        \xdipchip@if@pin{\numpins+1-\pgf@circ@count@a}
                          {%
                            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right+\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                          }
                          {%
                            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                          }%
                    \fi
                    \advance\pgf@circ@count@a by -1\relax%
                \repeatpgfmathloop
                \pgfusepath{stroke}
            \endpgfscope
            \fi
        }%
        % \pgf@sh@s@<name of the shape here> contains all the code for the shape
        % and is executed just before a node is drawn.
        \pgfutil@g@addto@macro\pgf@sh@s@xdipchip{%
            % Start with the maximum pin number and go backwards.
            \pgf@circ@count@a=\numpins\relax
            \pgfmathloop%
            \ifnum\pgf@circ@count@a>0
                % we will create two anchors per pin: the "normal one" like `pin 1` for the
                % electrical contact, and the "border one" like `bpin 1` for labels.
                % they will coincide if `external pins width` is set to 0.
                %% CHANGES HERE
                \xdipchip@if@pin\pgf@circ@count@a
                  {%
                    \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@xdipchip@pin\space\the\pgf@circ@count@a\endcsname{%
                        \noexpand\pgf@circ@dippinanchor{\the\pgf@circ@count@a}{1}%
                    }
                  }
                  {%
                    \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@xdipchip@pin\space\the\pgf@circ@count@a\endcsname{%
                        \noexpand\pgf@circ@dippinanchor{\the\pgf@circ@count@a}{0}%
                    }
                  }%
                \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@xdipchip@bpin\space\the\pgf@circ@count@a\endcsname{%
                    \noexpand\pgf@circ@dippinanchor{\the\pgf@circ@count@a}{0}%
                }
                \advance\pgf@circ@count@a by -1\relax%
                \repeatpgfmathloop%
            }%
        }

\makeatother

\ctikzset{
 logic ports=ieee,
 logic ports/scale=0.7,
 multipoles/dipchip/width=2
 }

\tikzset
  {
    block/.style={xdipchip
                 ,no topmark
                 ,hide numbers
                 ,external pins width=0.2
                 ,xdip pins={#1}}
  }

\newcommand*{\myblock}[1]{% Add #1- to the node and coord names
  node[block={1,2,3}, num pins=6](#1-FF){SR-FF}
  (#1-FF.pin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[and port, anchor=out](#1-AND1){}
  (#1-FF.pin 3) -- (#1-FF.pin 3 -| #1-AND1.out) node[and port, anchor=out](#1-AND2){}
  (#1-AND1.in 1) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(#1-in) to (#1-in |- #1-AND2.in 2) -- (#1-AND2.in 2);
}



\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw (0,0) \myblock{A};
  \draw (0,-4) \myblock{B};

  \draw (A-in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) node[below]{$a_0$};
  \draw (B-in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) node[below]{$a_1$};
  \draw (A-AND1.in 2) to[short, -*] (A-AND2.in 1)
    to[short, -*] (B-AND1.in 2) to[short, -*] (B-AND2.in 1)
    -- ++(0, -2) coordinate(down) node[below]{ENABLE};
    \draw
      (A-FF.pin 2) 
      to[short, -*] (B-FF.pin 2) 
      -- (B-FF.pin 2 |- down) node[below]{CP};
  % to show that anchors are placed where they should
  \draw
    (5, 0)
    node[xdipchip, xdip pins={1, 6, 8, 4}](XDIP){}
    ;
  \foreach\x in {1,...,8}
    \draw[red] (XDIP.pin \x) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A version that doesn't rely on `expl3` (by implementing an own quick list parsing/setting macro and else using `pgfutil`; this will use `Q` with category code 3 as the delimiter for our list, the same token is used elsewhere in `pgf` (namely in the space trimming code) as a delimiter, so this shouldn't be less stable than these parts of `pgf`).

The code block here only contains the definitions of `\xdipchip@if@pin`, the `xdip pins` key, and the necessary utility macros.

```
\makeatletter
% we'll use Q of category 3 as a delimiter of lists.
\catcode`\Q=3
% check whether something is contained in a list of comma separated values
% list should have a leading and trailing comma around each value
\def\xdipchip@if@pin#1%
  {\expandafter\xdipchip@if@pin@a\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1}}
\def\xdipchip@if@pin@a#1%
  {\expandafter\xdipchip@if@pin@b\expandafter{\xdipchip@pin@list}{#1}}
\def\xdipchip@if@pin@b#1#2%
  {%
    \begingroup
      \pgfutil@in@{Q#2Q}{#1}%
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \ifpgfutil@in@
      \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }
% setting a list just needs some quick parsing, firs stripping spaces from
% either end, and ignoring blank/empty elements.
\def\xdipchip@set@list#1#2%
  {%
    \edef#1%
      {Q\xdipchip@set@list@sanitize#2,\xdipchip@set@list,\xdipchip@set@list}%
  }
% quick way to check whether list parsing is done by gobbling up to a marker, in
% this case the marker is \xdipchip@set@list
\def\xdipchip@set@list@sanitize@checkend#1\xdipchip@set@list{}
% will only be called after the last element is handled, will gobble the
% remainder of the current sanitizing step
\def\xdipchip@set@list@sanitize@end\xdipchip@set@list#1\xdipchip@set@list{}
% grabs the next list element, checks whether we're done, and if not sanitizes
% it (meaning stripping spaces from either end).
\def\xdipchip@set@list@sanitize#1,%
  {%
    \xdipchip@set@list@sanitize@checkend
      #1\xdipchip@set@list@sanitize@end\xdipchip@set@list
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \xdipchip@set@list@sanitize@
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\pgfutil@trimspaces{#1}}%
  }
% we'll protect any argument from further expanding using \unexpanded, and
  % ignore empty/blank elements
\def\xdipchip@set@list@sanitize@#1%
  {%
    \pgfutil@ifempty{#1}%
      {}% ignore empty elements
      {\unexpanded{#1}Q}%
    \xdipchip@set@list@sanitize % get next element
  }
\catcode`\Q=11

\pgfkeys{/tikz/xdip pins/.code=\xdipchip@set@list\xdipchip@pin@list{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Nice, I like it. Would it work also in `context` or the  latex3 thing is LaTeX-only?

Comment: @Rmano `expl3` is (or was, no idea of the current state) loadable in `context` and plain, but I can quickly implement a complete independent code variant that only relies on `pgfutil`. Give me a few minutes (or hours? who knows?).

Comment: I have accepted this one because I like how the actual circuit description remains the same, with no extra drawing code needed.

Comment: @Skillmon @Rmano unfortunately I've found a weird bug with this: if I am connecting an `xdipchip` pin to another `xdipchip`'s pin, then the pin's base coordinate is used instead of its end coordinate: https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/5c41ba94cb877b5a9efb084a4eb13fc3

Comment: @Cactus is that with the `expl3` variant or the other code?

Comment: @Skillmon this is with the first variant.

Comment: The problem is that the anchor is calculated with the current value of `xdip pins` --- they are not "saved anchors". I will think a solution, but basically the list of pins must be saved as a `\savedmacro` in the shape.

Comment: @Rmano oh, ok (I have no idea about the internals of pgf shapes :) Wouldn't then `\savedmacro\xdippins{\let\xdippins\xdipchip@pin@list}` suffice? And changing the `\xdipchip@if@pin` function to check the list `\xdippins` instead of `\xdipchip@pin@list`?

Comment: @Cactus thanks for pointing out this bug. We're currently trying to fix this, if this succeeds this might be added as a feature to the normal `dipchip`.

Comment: @Cactus thanks to Skillmon's code there will be a `draw only pins=...` feature in the next release of `circuitikz`, for chips and muxdemuxes (as soon as things are tested a bit). You can have a peek by looking at the bleeding edge manual here: https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/

Answer (score 2):

Although @Skillmon's answer is nice and elegant, what I will do for the next release of `circuitikz` is making `dipchip` and `qfpchip` respect the `no input leads` option as the multiplexer are already doing. It's a minimal change really, the idea is the following:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{dipchip}{
    \savedmacro{\ctikzclass}{\edef\ctikzclass{chips}}
    \saveddimen{\scaledRlen}{\pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
    \savedmacro\numpins{%
            \pgf@circ@count@a=\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/num pins}%
            \def\numpins{\the\pgf@circ@count@a}
    }
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
        \pgf@x=-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y=-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by+.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }%
    \savedanchor\origin{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \anchor{center}{\origin}
    \anchor{text}{\centerpoint}% to adjust text
    \saveddimen\height{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{((\numpins)
        *\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing})*\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen/2}%
    }%
    \saveddimen{\chipspacing}{
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen*\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing}}}
    \saveddimen{\width}{
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen*\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/width}}}
    \saveddimen{\extshift}{
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen*\ctikzvalof{multipoles/external pins width}}}
    % standard anchors
    \savedanchor\northwest{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{0.5*((\numpins)
        *\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing})*\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen/2}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{-0.5*\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen*\ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/width}}
    }
    \anchor{dot}{\northwest
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@x + 0.3*\chipspacing}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@y - 0.3*\chipspacing}
    }
    \anchor{nw}{\northwest}
    \anchor{ne}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{se}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{sw}{\northwest\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{north west}{\northwest}
    \anchor{north east}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{south east}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x \pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{south west}{\northwest\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{n}{\northwest\pgf@x=0pt }
    \anchor{e}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x\pgf@y=0pt }
    \anchor{s}{\northwest\pgf@x=0pt\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{w}{\northwest\pgf@y=0pt }
    \anchor{north}{\northwest\pgf@x=0pt }
    \anchor{east}{\northwest\pgf@x=-\pgf@x\pgf@y=0pt }
    \anchor{south}{\northwest\pgf@x=0pt\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{west}{\northwest\pgf@y=0pt }
    % start drawing
    \backgroundpath{%
        \northwest
        \pgf@circ@res@up = \pgf@y
        \pgf@circ@res@down = -\pgf@y
        \pgf@circ@res@right = -\pgf@x
        \pgf@circ@res@left = \pgf@x
        \pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen=\scaledRlen
        \pgf@circ@res@step = \ctikzvalof{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing}\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen
        \pgf@circ@res@other = \ctikzvalof{multipoles/external pins width}\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen
        \pgfscope% (for the line width)
        \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{multipoles}{\pgflinewidth}
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-\width/2}{-\height/2}}{\pgfpoint{\width/2}{\height/2}}%
        \pgf@circ@draworfill
        %% upside mark
        \ifpgf@circuit@chip@topmark
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.2*\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpatharc{0}{180}{0.2*\pgf@circ@res@left}
        \fi
        \pgfusepath{stroke}%
        \pgfsetcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
        % Adding the pin number
        \ifpgf@circuit@chip@shownumbers
            \pgf@circ@count@a=\numpins\relax
            \divide\pgf@circ@count@a by 2 \pgf@circ@count@b=\pgf@circ@count@a
            % thanks to @marmot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473571/38080
            \ifpgf@circuit@chip@straightnumbers
                \pgfgettransformentries\a\b\temp\temp\temp\temp
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{-atan2(\b,\a)}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\quadrant}{mod(4+int(360+(\rot+45)/90),4)}
            \else
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{0}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\quadrant}{0}
            \fi
            \def\pgf@circ@strut{\vrule width 0pt height 1em depth 0.4em\relax}
            \def\mytext{\ctikzvalof{multipoles/font}\space\pgf@circ@strut\the\pgf@circ@count@c\space}
            \pgfmathloop%
            \ifnum\pgf@circ@count@a>0
                \ifcase\quadrant % rotation 0
                    % left
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\pgf@circ@count@a
                    \pgftext[left,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                    % right
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\numexpr2*\pgf@circ@count@b-\pgf@circ@count@a+1\relax
                    \pgftext[right,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                \or % rotation -90
                    % left
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\pgf@circ@count@a
                    \pgftext[top,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                    % right
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\numexpr2*\pgf@circ@count@b-\pgf@circ@count@a+1\relax
                    \pgftext[bottom,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                \or %rotation 180
                    % left
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\pgf@circ@count@a
                    \pgftext[right,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                    % right
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\numexpr2*\pgf@circ@count@b-\pgf@circ@count@a+1\relax
                    \pgftext[left,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                \or % rotation +90
                    % left
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\pgf@circ@count@a
                    \pgftext[bottom,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                    % right
                    \pgf@circ@count@c=\numexpr2*\pgf@circ@count@b-\pgf@circ@count@a+1\relax
                    \pgftext[top,
                        at=\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step},
                        rotate=\rot]{\mytext}
                \fi
                \advance\pgf@circ@count@a-1\relax%
                \repeatpgfmathloop
            \fi
            \endpgfscope
            % draw external pins or pads
            \ifdim\pgf@circ@res@other>0pt
            \ifpgfcirc@draw@input@leads
            \pgfscope
                \pgfsetlinewidth{\ctikzvalof{multipoles/external pins thickness}\pgflinewidth}
                \pgf@circ@count@a=\numpins\relax
                \divide\pgf@circ@count@a by 2 \pgf@circ@count@b=\pgf@circ@count@a
                \pgfmathloop%
                \ifnum\pgf@circ@count@a>0
                    \edef\padfrac{\ctikzvalof{multipoles/external pad fraction}}
                    \ifnum\padfrac>0
                        \pgf@circ@res@temp=\pgf@circ@res@step\divide\pgf@circ@res@temp by \padfrac
                        % left side pads
                        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgf@circ@res@other}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        % right side pads
                        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right+\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right+\pgf@circ@res@other}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                    \else
                        % left side pins
                        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        % right side pins
                        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right+\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up+(\pgf@circ@dip@pin@shift-\the\pgf@circ@count@a)*\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                    \fi
                    \advance\pgf@circ@count@a by -1\relax%
                \repeatpgfmathloop
                \pgfusepath{stroke}
            \endpgfscope
            \fi
            \fi
        }%
        % \pgf@sh@s@<name of the shape here> contains all the code for the shape
        % and is executed just before a node is drawn.
        \pgfutil@g@addto@macro\pgf@sh@s@dipchip{%
            % Start with the maximum pin number and go backwards.
            \pgf@circ@count@a=\numpins\relax
            \pgfmathloop%
            \ifnum\pgf@circ@count@a>0
                % we will create two anchors per pin: the "normal one" like `pin 1` for the
                % electrical contact, and the "border one" like `bpin 1` for labels.
                % they will coincide if `external pins width` is set to 0.
                \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@dipchip@pin\space\the\pgf@circ@count@a\endcsname{%
                    \noexpand\pgf@circ@dippinanchor{\the\pgf@circ@count@a}{1}%
                }
                \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@dipchip@bpin\space\the\pgf@circ@count@a\endcsname{%
                    \noexpand\pgf@circ@dippinanchor{\the\pgf@circ@count@a}{0}%
                }
                \advance\pgf@circ@count@a by -1\relax%
                \repeatpgfmathloop%
            }%
        }

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{
 logic ports=ieee,
 logic ports/scale=0.7,
 multipoles/dipchip/width=2
 }

\tikzset{block/.style=
  { dipchip
  , no topmark
  , hide numbers
  , external pins width=0.2
  , no input leads
  }
}

\newcommand*{\myblock}[1]{% Add #1- to the node and coord names
node[block, num pins=6](#1-FF){SR-FF}
(#1-FF.bpin 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[and port, anchor=out](#1-AND1){} %use bpin here
(#1-FF.bpin 3) -- (#1-FF.pin 3 -| #1-AND1.out) node[and port, anchor=out](#1-AND2){}
(#1-AND1.in 1) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(#1-in) to (#1-in |- #1-AND2.in 2) -- (#1-AND2.in 2)
(#1-FF.pin 2) -- (#1-FF.bpin 2); %draw the pin explicitly here
}


\begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw (0,0) \myblock{A};
  \draw (0,-4) \myblock{B};

  \draw (A-in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) node[below]{$a_0$};
  \draw (B-in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) node[below]{$a_1$};
  \draw (A-AND1.in 2) to[short, -*] (A-AND2.in 1)
    to[short, -*] (B-AND1.in 2) to[short, -*] (B-AND2.in 1)
    -- ++(0, -2) coordinate(down) node[below]{ENABLE};
    \draw
      (A-FF.pin 2)
      to[short, -*] (B-FF.pin 2)
      -- (B-FF.pin 2 |- down) node[below]{CP};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

So --- when you choose `no inputs leads` you have all the anchors but no pins in any places; you just choose to use `bpin X` or `pin X` for the connection and you can draw a pin just connecting the `bpin` to the `pin` anchor.

[image]

Comment: I don't like that this will pollute the code with extra lines just to connect the "point where the lead would end" with the "point where the pin is" to draw the lead.

Comment: Yes, that was the idea when I said that @Skillmon 's code is more elegant.

Comment: Anyway, I merged https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/548 for now, it's a nice symmetrical thing anyway. Still thinking about the nice solution.