# \pgfdeclareshape: how to define anchors in a loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach, circuitikz

I think my question is quite similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146742/18520) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65192/18520),
however I didn't manage to modify the provided solutions to fit my problem.

In the following MWE I am trying to define 8 pin anchors in a `\foreach` loop.
What I am doing is obviously wrong, as I am getting an *"Undefined control sequence"* error when I try to reference one of this pins.

Can someone provide a minimal example for a defining anchors in a loop?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

% BEGIN myic definition
\def\w{3cm}
\def\h{4.5cm}

\pgfdeclareshape{myic}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \anchor{text}
    {\pgfpoint{-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}}

    % PIN ANCHORS
    % The following code does not work as expected.
    % I am looking for a way to define \n anchors in a loop.
    \foreach \n in {0,...,7}
        {\anchor{in\n}{\pgfpoint{.5*\w}{7*.25cm-\n*.5cm}}}

    \foregroundpath{
        % RECTANGLE
        \pgfsetlinewidth{0.025cm}
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{.5*\w}{.5*\h}}{\pgfpoint{-.5*\w}{-.5*\h}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}

        % PIN NAMES
        \foreach \n in {0,...,7}
            {\pgftext[right,at={\pgfpoint{.5*\w-.1cm}{7*.25cm-\n*.5cm}}]{\scriptsize IN\n}}
    }
}
% END myic definition

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[myic] (u0) {U0};
    \draw (u0.in0) to[short,-o] ++(1,0); % <- ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Here is what I have so far, the red line with a circle is what I am not able to create:

[image: tikzcircuit ic]

Comment: How about this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65192/how-to-generate-many-anchors-inside-pgfdeclareshape ?

Comment: @percusse Many thanks. It's one of the links in my question -- and I finally figured out how to modify your answer to fit my problem.

Comment: Oh must have clicked the link twice and confused myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to apply [percusee's answer (here)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65208/18520) to my problem.
It works with the following loop:

```
\makeatletter
\foreach \n in {0,...,7}{
    \xdef\doanchor{
        \noexpand\anchor{in\n}{
            \noexpand\pgfpoint{.5*\w}{7*.25cm-\n*.5cm}
        }
    }
    \doanchor
}
\makeatother
```